# Messenger for Desktop is not working (Loki)

Tags: release-loki, thirdpartyapps

I installed messenger for desktop .deb package (downloaded it from its official site). When I open it, it tries to update javascript and whatever option (update, cancel, close) I choose it does not work.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not actually updating JavaScript, rather because it is an Electron app, the dialogue title is just 'JavaScript' by default. Does running `/opt/messengerfordesktop/messengerfordesktop` in Terminal produce any useful messages?

Comment: I got this answer for that command -

bash: /opt/messengerfordesktop/messengerfordesktop: No such file or directory

Comment: In `/usr/share/applications` there should be a file named something like `messengerfordesktop.desktop`. Could you list its contents? If you can't find something like that, then please include the output of `ls /usr/share/applications`.

Comment: It has just started working properly (some updates might have fixed it?) the only thing which annoys me is the active window's icon in the dock.